# Taurus-JMeter Pass/Fail Criteria

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter, taurus

I'm executing a multi-scenario(multiple JMX) test through Taurus. I've set individual pass/fail criteria specific to scenarios at each scenario level in .yml file.
Currently, if a pass/fail criteria of a specific scenario fails, it stops the entire execution. I want only that scenario to stop. Would it be possible to stop a specific scenario?

Attaching snippet of my taurus .yml file for reference